# Android Studio 3.0: buildToolsVersion not found in gradle files

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0, build-tools

I recently installed new stable version of Android Studio (v3.0). Then created a new project and there was not any problem. But saw there is no `buildToolsVersion` field in the app-level `build.gradle` file.  Even I searched all project files (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>), but didn't find anything!

**What does this mean?** And how can I determine what is the version of Build Tools in my app module?

---

**build.gradle (Project):**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (Module: app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.e900.androidstudio30"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

With the new android gradle plugin 3.x **you no longer need to specify** a version for the build tools (so, you can now remove the `android.buildToolsVersion` property).
**By default**, the plugin automatically uses the **minimum required build tools version for the version of Android plugin** you're using.

You can read [more here](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-3-0-0-release-notes).

Comment: The URL points to something else entirely now. Perhaps it should have pointed to a specific plugin version changelog.

Comment: In Android Gradle plugin 3.2.0 you need to include the following in each module's build.gradle file: android.buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

Comment: @SargeBorsch I've updated the URL to point to the 3.0.0 release changes, which says: _"With this update, you no longer need to specify a version for the build tools—the plugin uses the minimum required version by default. So, you can now remove the android.buildToolsVersion property."_

Comment: it defaults to the latest version