# Where is Android Studio reading the build tools version?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting the error:

> WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2

It is actually an error breaking my build but this wasn't copyable so I found this line in the log (the only place I could find reference to "26.0.2"

I've searched (Ctrl-Shift-F) for 26.0.2 everywhere and found just 2 occurrences of 26 in one file, the "app" level build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 26
...
```

Which I changed to 27, my build tools is 27.0.3 which I use for other projects, I don't *want* another build tools. How can I communicate this to Android Studio?

[image: failed to install build-tools]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0 rc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019599/gradle-sync-failed-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-24-0-0-rc1)

Comment: @Eminem, I linked that in my answer, it is not a duplicate, this is far more specific

Comment: you can add an answer there,so that people can see it

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999419/android-studio-3-0-buildtoolsversion-not-found-in-gradle-files

Comment: @Eminem, the answer was found there, only after asking here

Answer (score 0):

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47425748/866333, I hope this offers easier sign posting:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    // Add the following line, Android Studio is quite good for filtering bloat.
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 27
        ...
```

I actually had to *add* a line, so I don't know where AS was reading 26.0.2 from, but this fix has worked on 2 of my projects. Oh, and because I'm now using the support lib (because its 2018):

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

will be on the wrong versions, fix by replacing the 3 occurrences of "26.1.0" with, eg, "27.1.1", as that was what the error messages was hinting at.

Comment: I am undeleting this answer because it is still the first one I find when I get this error.